# What does it mean for there to be a symmetry condition for a characteristic function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $\phi_X(t)$ is a characteristic function of some real-valued random variable $X$. We're told that we should assume the symmetry condition $\phi_X(t) = \phi_X(-t)$, or $\phi_X(t) \equiv 1$.

I understood $\phi_X(t) = \phi_X(-t)$ just to mean that $\phi_X$ is symmetric around the origin, but I don't understand the point of the ''or $\phi_X(t) \equiv 1$'' condition. Can someone help me gain some intuition?

Comment: There is not enough context here to answer the question.

Comment: Here's more context: We're told that the sample average (X1 + ... + Xn)/n, where Xi iid & E(Xi) = 0, cvs in law to some rv X, and we're asked to find the characteristic function of X under the symmetry condition as given above.

Comment: '$or \phi_X(t)\equiv 1$' indeed  does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a point.  The person posing the problem made a mistake.  They were thinking about the final answer, the possible distributions for $X$, and they wanted to account for the special case where $X\equiv 0$ is constant which corresponds to $\phi_X(t)=1$ for all $t$.  However, they didn't realize this isn't actually a special case, since $\phi_X(t)\equiv 1$ satisfies the more general symmetry condition $\phi_X(t)=\phi_X(-t)$.